# Rotate a Collada model around its own y-axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple three.js scene that contains a 3D Homer Simpson, on a plane. I want to be able to spin him around on his own y-axis, using the mouse.

The following code is *almost* there. It's bit I've cobbled together from here and there and my own bits. The problem is that I am just not able to get spin him around his y-axis, one that would be running right through his core, right in the middle.

In the included code, if I use the frame as a reference, he spins around in a circle. The circumference of which (and just by chance in this example) is about the size of the plane he's standing on.

If I remove the frame and instead rotate using the *model*, then he *almost* spins around on his y-axis -- except that the I axis is just to his side.

I am using the following [model](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=37114f8a36351d50e4a4d9ecf0f14439&prevstart=12). In fact, the way I want him to spin is the way he does in the 3D Warehouse example. If you click on *3D View* and spin him, you'll see what I am trying to achieve.

```
// nasty globals, but this is just a sandbox.
var camera;
var frame;
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var model;
var plane;
var renderer;
var scene;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
var targetRotation = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
var windowHalfX = 800 / 2;

loader.load('Homer/models/body.dae', function(collada) {
    model = collada.scene;

    model.position.x = 0;
    model.position.y = 0;
    model.position.z = 100;

    model.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;       // stand Homer upright and facing the camera.

    init();
    animate();
});

function init()
{
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(800, 800);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 100, 10000);

    camera.position.x = 50;
    camera.position.y = 120;
    camera.position.z = 600;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(model);

    // Do I need a frame of reference to get Homer to spin on his own Y-axis instead of the scene's?
    frame = new THREE.Object3D();
    frame.add(model);
    scene.add(frame);

    plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 400, 400 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0 } ) );
    plane.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );
    scene.add( plane );

    var light = new THREE.SpotLight();
    light.position.set(200, 500, 4000);
    scene.add(light);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Spin Homer around when moving the mouse around
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
}


function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

    mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
}

function onDocumentMouseMove() {
    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp() {
    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
}

function onDocumentMouseOut() {
    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
}

function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
    if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
    }
}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
    if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;
    }
}

// Spin Homer around the Y-Axis
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    // When we add the frame, he spins in a circle, about the size of the plane (that's spin size if coincidence)
    frame.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - frame.rotation.y ) * 0.03;

    // If we remove the frame from the scene, and use this line instead, Homer spins around the y-axis.
    // But, the y-axis is along the outside of his leg and arm, not through his vertical center, which is what I want.
    // model.rotation.z += ( targetRotation - model.rotation.z ) * 0.03;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is tricky. The problem is that Homer's geometry has him standing in his local coordinate system with his right foot next to the origin.

What you would normallly do in a case like this is call

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( -distance, 0, 0 ) );
```

and translate the geometry along the local x-axis. That would center Homer, and you'd be done.

If you can figure out the Collada data structure, you can do that.

Another solution is this trick: (1) make your model a child of a parent, (2) make the parent a child of another object, (3) and then offset the parent by some distance:

In your `init()` function, do this

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(800, 800);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 1, 100, 10000 );
camera.position.x = 50;
camera.position.y = 120;
camera.position.z = 600;
scene.add( camera ); // don't forget this

scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper() ); // frame of reference

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////
// trick to accommodate geometry offset
object = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( object );

parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.position.x = -39;
object.add( parent );

parent.add( model );
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And then in your `animate()` function:

```
object.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - object.rotation.y ) * 0.03;
```