# Three.js - move custom geometry to origin

Tags: rotation, three.js

I have some custom geometries obtained from a STEP file conversion and I use the mouse to rotate them. They rotate around the origin of the scene, but since they are far from it, they seem rotating on a virtual sphere. How can I move them to the origin so that they don't seem "floating" around (I mean that I'd like to reduce to zero the radius of the virtual sphere). [This is the example I'd like to move](http://sygest.agintersys.com/testing.html). I've tried setting their position to (0, 0, 0) doing:

```
object.position.x = 0;
object.position.y = 0;
object.position.z = 0;
```

but it didin't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The typical solution to this problem is to translate the geometry right after it is created. You do that by applying a translation matrix to the geometry like so:

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( distX, distY, distZ ) );
```

EDIT: You can simply do this, instead:

```
geometry.translate( distX, distY, distZ ); // three.js r.72
```

The function `geometry.computeBoundingBox()` may be of help to you in determining an amount to translate.

However, I see in your case, you have multiple geometries, so it it a bit more complicated, but doable. You will need to translate each geometry by the same amount.

EDIT

Tip: Instead of adding each object to the scene, create a parent object, add it to the scene, and then add the objects to the parent.

```
var parent;

parent = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( parent );

parent.add( object1 );
parent.add( object2 );
// and so on...
```

Then in your render function, just rotate the parent, not the individual objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the parent object doesn't seem to change the situation, so I'll try the first suggestion

Comment: The parent-object suggestion was not part of the solution, just a friendly tip. :-)  If you chose to implement it, see the "trick" in the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795775/rotate-a-collada-model-around-its-own-y-axis as a alternate way to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh now I understood thanks ;-) I created an object, I added the parent to it and then all the geometries to the parent. But I still don't understand how I can move the parent to the origin. If I use the computeBoundingBox() function for the parent and then I get the center of the bounding box, should I move the parent there?

Comment: Since you have decided to use the parent trick, and not translate the geometry itself, try `parent.position.set( -800, 300, -800 )` and see if it gets better. This would be more like the negative of the original bounding box, which you could compute exactly.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but it's not getting better. I've updated the page http://sygest.agintersys.com/testing.html
I used:
object = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( object );

parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.position.set( -800, 300, -800 )
object.add( parent );

parent.add( object0 );
parent.add( object1 );
...

Comment: The 0.27 scale factor is playing into this... Leave the scale factor and set `parent.position.set( -230, 100, -230 );`