# How can I rotate around the center of an object in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am dynamically adding a number of different objects of various sizes into a scene (one per click) and scaling and positioning them. Now I want to be able to rotate the objects around the Y axis at their center. I have added a boundingBox and an axesHelper, but the latter is showing up in the bottom corner of the objects. Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835361/three-js-move-custom-geometry-to-origin/12835749#12835749), which is similar to mine, it seems like this might be because of an offset. I can find the center of the object fine with this:

```
var box3 = new THREE.Box3();
var boundingBox = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh, 0xffff00 );
scene.add( boundingBox );
box3.setFromObject( boundingBox );
center = box3.getCenter( boundingBox.position );
console.log( "center: ", center );
```

But when I try to reset the center to this position, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848863/threejs-how-to-rotate-around-objects-own-center-instead-of-world-center/28860849), my object shoots way off into space.

```
box3.center(mesh.position);
mesh.position.multiplyScalar( -1 );
```

And I’m not really clear (even after reading the documentation) what “multiplyScalar” does/means. By playing with that number, I can get the object closer to the desired position, but the object still doesn't rotate around its center, and the AxesHelper is still at the original location.

Comment: Instead, try translating the vertices of your mesh's geometry: `mesh.geometry.center()`.

Comment: Oof! Of course! Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd like to accept your solution, @WestLangley, if you'd like to move it to an answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped, but I previously posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not rotating around its center. Likely, your object's geometry is offset from the origin.

If you are dealing with a single Mesh or Line, you can center the object's geometry by calling

```
geometry.center();
```

This method will translate the vertices of the geometry so the geometry's bounding box is centered at the origin.

three.js r.97